# micronaut testcontainers postgrsql spawing multiple containers

Tags: kotlin, flyway, micronaut, testcontainers

I have a micronaut+kotlin application. I am using testcontainers to perform integration/functional test code.
I have a docker-compose file with two containers:

```
services:
  # starts up mock services
  mockyeah:
    image: mockyeah:latest
    ports:
      - "4001:4001"
    volumes:
      - ./mockyeah/services:/mockyeah/services
      - ./mockyeah/index.js:/mockyeah/index.js

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.5-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

For initializing the data, I am using flyway and postgresql config, below is the config I have in application-test.yml:

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:13.5-alpine://localhost:5432/test_db?TC_DAEMON=true
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    schema: test-schema
    driverClassName: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver

flyway:
  datasources:
    default:
      enabled: true
      locations:
        - classpath:db/integration/migration
```

What I observed is when I execute the command: `./gradlew clean test` , the app will start up the containers. When I execute the command `watch docker ps -a` I can see mockyeah and postgresql containers.
But then when the flyway is trying to configure, its actually starting another postgres container on a random port, generally on 41XXX. The app goes through the test scenarios but fails because the app is unable to see the data from the test DB.

I am trying to figure out why there are two postgreql conatiners started and why the app even though I have given the right configs is looking into a DB where flyway did not add any data.

logs:

```
 Creating container for image: docker/compose:1.29.2
 Container docker/compose:1.29.2 is starting: 474159194d362b0e0ee93ef8b7ac49f70cde9a6710375940007b17f97c6568a1
 Container docker/compose:1.29.2 started in PT3.754696S
 Docker Compose container is running for command: up -d
STDERR: Creating network "o1twbyuzwqaf_default" with the default driver
STDERR: Creating o1twbyuzwqaf_mockyeah_1 ...
STDERR: Creating o1twbyuzwqaf_postgres_1 ...
STDERR: Creating o1twbyuzwqaf_postgres_1 ... done
STDERR: Creating o1twbyuzwqaf_mockyeah_1 ... done

c.z.h.HikariConfig:1092 - HikariPool-1 - idleTimeout has been set but has no effect because the pool is operating as a fixed size pool.
c.z.h.HikariDataSource:80 - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
?.5-alpine]:376 - Creating container for image: postgres:13.5-alpine
?.5-alpine]:440 - Container postgres:13.5-alpine is starting: f7b157c5beb3f8d5cc153075f91c162983bdf2dd235fc377f6c0a2df6a73e04c
?.5-alpine]:520 - Container postgres:13.5-alpine started in PT2.449402S
c.z.h.HikariDataSource:82 - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
i.m.f.AbstractFlywayMigration:96 - Running migrations for database with qualifier [default]
o.f.c.i.l.VersionPrinter:37 - Flyway Community Edition 8.5.13 by Redgate
o.f.c.i.l.VersionPrinter:37 - See what's new here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#8.5.13
o.f.c.i.l.VersionPrinter:37 -
o.f.c.i.d.b.BaseDatabaseType:37 - Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:49175/test_db (PostgreSQL 13.5)
o.f.c.i.d.b.Schema:37 - Creating schema "test_schema" ...
o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory:37 - Creating Schema History table "test_schema"."flyway_schema_history" ...
o.f.c.i.c.DbMigrate:37 - Current version of schema "test_schema": null
o.f.c.i.c.DbMigrate:37 - Migrating schema "test_schema" to version "99 - CreateTable test-table"
o.f.c.i.c.DbMigrate:37 - Successfully applied 1 migration to schema "test_schema", now at version v99 (execution time 00:00.163s)
```